# Android network error

Tags: java, android, networking

Okay, so I have narrowed it down to where I am finding my error. My emulator DOES have a working connection but when I run my app it just gives me a "checking network" message that I threw in and doesn't get past it. After throwing in a lot of logs, I think I narrowed it down.

```
protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
    Log.d("am i stuck", "AM i stuck?");
    return null;
}
```

When I call my custon AsyncTask.execute() class it  doesnt get past that method. What do I have to return? Am I doing it wrong? It doesn't get to my post execute or anything.

Comment: is there an @Override on top of the method? Sometimes the compiler doesnt recognize it as an override if the annotation is missing

Comment: Yeah there is, @Roadblock. I have made another doInBackground method that takes in a String but it never gets called. Instead it calls the one that takes in an object.

Comment: Can you post your complete code. It seems you are overriding the doInBackground Method. I doubt if this is possible as you have to pass in the parameter types while extending AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I am currently working in a group and didn't see that a person in my group had made their own custom doInBackground method that was doing all the code. I just had to put that in the overridden method and all was good. Thank you for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

> Am I doing it wrong?

It depends on what you are trying to do.

> It doesn't get to my post execute or anything.

First understand your code:

A -> Do in Background function is on worker thread and expects you to do something here, like make network calls.

B -> return from doInBackground is argument to onPostExecute() which is null in your case.

C -> What is in your onPostExecute() code? Why have you even created an AsyncTask if you are not doing anything in doInBackground?